# Indexed data not getting shared in Elaasticsearch Cluster 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I installed elasticsearch as `RPM` service.

I have 5 cluster nodes in which one is `tribe node`, three are `master and data node` and final one is `data node`. I pointed logstash to that data node and it was successfully indexded. When I just checked in other boxes the indexed information is not shared among the clusters.

When I checked the url xxx.xx.xx:9200/. I am getting new field called cluster_uuid whcich I didn't see in my previous version of ELK(2.3.1).. I am suspecting due to that different cluster_uuid.

**node1**

```
{
  "name" : "node2",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster_sft",
  "cluster_uuid" : "wwbCT_wJRryT6ko-g_lm7A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "db0d481",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-09T22:05:32.386Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**node 2:**

```
{
  "name" : "node3",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster_sft",
  "cluster_uuid" : "qq3YUgZGR9O7nBXTLe8SUg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "db0d481",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-09T22:05:32.386Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**Here is my elasticsearch config**

```
cluster.name: cluster_sft

node.name: node1

node.master: true

node.data: true

bootstrap.memory_lock: true

http.host: xx.xx.xxx.xxx

network.host: 127.0.0.1

http.port: 9200

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9200","xx.xx.xxx.xxx;9200","xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9200","xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9200"]

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

I am not sure whether I am missing any attributes or I am going wrong in configuration.

Thanks,
Rajeshkumar

Comment: Did you check output of following command `GET _cat/nodes?v` ?

Comment: @avr Yes the output from `GET _cat/nodes?v`                                          `127.0.0.1 15 52 0 0.00 0.01 0.05 mdi * node1`

Comment: I don't get it. How many clusters do you have? And why are you using a tribe node?

Comment: @Mangoski They are not formed as single cluster. Change this setting `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1` to `2`. And check ES logs in all nodes why they are failing to join single cluster.

Comment: @AndreiStefan. I am having one cluster with 5 nodes. Tribe node is my requirement to set it up

Comment: @avr. When I changed the `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1 to 2`. It was joining in the cluster. When I start the kibana . Kibana throwing `service unavailable elasticsearch node is in red status`. I couldn't figure out the failure.

Comment: check whether your `ES` is up and running when you started kibana

Comment: @avr yes its up and running

Comment: probably elasticsearch service might not be reachable from `kibana` server! Did you check you have access to ES port  from `kibana` server?